# How to count non-blank answers in a list of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have averaged values across a number of non-contiguous discrete cells in a row using the average function, which conveniently ignores blank cells. These cells are computed by array formulas and so many of them contain `""` (generated by an `iferror`). There are many intervening cells containing other kinds of unrelated data so I'm unable to use column ranges. The average calculation is done via:

```
=IFERROR(ROUND(AVERAGE(H3,J3,N3,O3,S3,T3,V3,W3,Y3,AC3,AD3,AE3,AG3,AI3,AM3,AN3,AO3,AP3,AQ3,AS3,AW3,AY3,BA3,BB3,BG3,BH3,BJ3,BK3,BL3,BN3,BO3,BU3,BV3,BX3,CD3,CE3,CG3,CI3,CM3,CN3,CO3,CP3,CR3,CS3,CT3,CV3,CZ3,DA3,DB3,DD3,DE3,DG3,DH3),0),"")
```

which works just fine. I also want to count how many non-blank cells were present. However the `COUNTA` function does not ignore the `""` values, so this returns the total number of cells present:

```
=COUNTA(H4,J4,N4,O4,S4,T4,V4,W4,Y4,AC4,AD4,AE4,AG4,AI4,AM4,AN4,AO4,AP4,AQ4,AS4,AW4,AY4,BA4,BB4,BG4,BH4,BJ4,BK4,BL4,BN4,BO4,BU4,BV4,BX4,CD4,CE4,CG4,CI4,CM4,CN4,CO4,CP4,CR4,CS4,CT4,CV4,CZ4,DA4,DB4,DD4,DE4,DG4,DH4)
```

The various solutions for overcoming this problem, like using `COUNTIF` and `SUMPRODUCT` only work on cell ranges. How can I easily do this without having a count formula for each cell individually?

Any formula used will be auto-propagated down many many rows in a sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT with CHOOSE to return the array:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE(ROW($1:$53),H4,J4,N4,O4,S4,T4,V4,W4,Y4,AC4,AD4,AE4,AG4,AI4,AM4,AN4,AO4,AP4,AQ4,AS4,AW4,AY4,BA4,BB4,BG4,BH4,BJ4,BK4,BL4,BN4,BO4,BU4,BV4,BX4,CD4,CE4,CG4,CI4,CM4,CN4,CO4,CP4,CR4,CS4,CT4,CV4,CZ4,DA4,DB4,DD4,DE4,DG4,DH4)<>""))
```

Comment: do all the "blanks" contain a formula that returns the empty string?

Comment: Then it should work.  Maybe it needs to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to force the array.  I tested on Office 365 which not longer requires it.

Comment: Yes: That was it. As the cells are generated by an array formula, this cell needs the cntrl-shift-enter! Magic

Comment: look at the data.  this only works on cells that are equal to `""` .  True blanks register as `0` not `""`